# Angular 6:I want to disable all below options of sidebar and enable above options in condition from local storage

Tags: angular, ngfor, disabled-control

I have an array which I am iterating of ngFor and array is:

```
Form_Array: any[] = ["Contact Details","PAN","Aadhaar","Basic 
   Details","Address","Regulatory Info","Segments",
  "Document Upload", "Brokerage", "Review", "In-person verification"
  ];
```

I am getting some API response which I am setting on localStorage.

I want if I am getting "AAdhar" from API response than all above links should be enabled to click including "Aadhar" and rest below elements should be disabled.

[Here is the image of that grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DFdz.png)

Please suggest me what should I do?

Here is HTML template :

```
<div class="border-5">
  <div class="index-layout" *ngFor="let form_feild of Form_Array;let i=index" (click)="showForm(form_feild)">

    <p class="font-type"><span class="padd_align" >{{i+1}}</span>{{form_feild}}</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Put here your code and also the html template so that we can help you

Comment: @NoorAShuvo I have added html template and nothing with the code side yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could enable or disable link for grid content based on the index value in the response. 
Implementation would be

- Find the "Aadhar" index in response array 'aadharIndex'
- Enable link if the index of current values less than 'aadharIndex' otherwise disable it.

Comment: But at same the same time I have to match that index value with the localStorage to match the condition. and enable previous items and disable next one. And this is not only for Aadhar it is about any item with comes from response.

Answer (score 0):

First, find the index.

```
 var in= Form_Array.indexOf("Aadhaar");
```

Then, apply

```
<div class="border-5">
  <div class="index-layout" *ngFor="let form_feild of Form_Array;let i=index" ng-disable="i>in" (click)="showForm(form_feild)">

    <p class="font-type"><span class="padd_align" >{{i+1}}</span>{{form_feild}}</p></div>
</div>
```